# Avoid triggering multiple actions within the same div in JQuery (dropdown, delete and sort)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with the triggering of multiple action taken in the same div.
It's composed by a banner with a dropdown, and in the banner there is a button to delete it and a button to move it. Now, if I click the `delete` button it will ask if I am sure to delete it, and it will open the dropdown too. I fixed this by adding the `stopPropagation`, but now I have added a button to move it, where the `stopPropagation` make it useless. How should I fix this situation?

```
<div id="question_area" class="sortable">
   <div class="clickable" onMouseDown="toggleMenu()">
     <a href="deleteThisQuestion" onMouseDown="stopEvent(event)" </a> 
     <span><img src='img'/>You can sort this div by dragging the image</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your html and javascript in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: The code is too long to post it in jsfiddle, sorry.

Comment: What about just trying to replicate the issue in jsfiddle? Your wording is confusing - your main div is composed by a banner with a dropdown? And what do your `toggleMenu` and `stopPropogation` functions look like?